# Specify logging configuration for Java code executed by Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, slf4j

I have a legacy Gradle build script that executes a lot of Java code. Some of the Java code uses libraries that spit out debug-like output on info level. I would like to fine tune this logging but would rather not silence *all* info logging by invoking Gradle with `--warn`.

Is there a way to, for example, pass a `log.properties` to Gradle, to configure Gradles `logger`?

(The Java library that Gradle calls into uses slf4j logging.)